# NSLayoutConstraint constrain centreX to another side of superview

Tags: cocoa, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

I can currently constrain the centreX of a view to the left side of its superview like so:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *con = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCentreX
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:view.superview
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                      multiplier:1
                                                        constant:20];
```

But this does not allow me to set the constraint's priority and so is quite restrictive.

My question is: **How do you achieve something similar using visual format language** (so that **priority** can also be set)?

Also note: I'd like this to be achieved with a single constraint only, for ease of use later on.

Answer (score 0):

Just recalled that the issue with calling `[con setPriority:priority]` only occurs when the constraint has already been installed in a view.

For my purposes, using constraintWithItem:Attribute:RelatedBy... and then calling con.priority=priority works fine.

Nonetheless, it would still be useful to know how to achieve something similar with VFL (if possible)